# Modifying LINQ to XML statement to grab specific data from nested xml

Tags: .net, xml, linq, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I was helped out in an earlier question on how to use Linq to XML, and I almost have it working, but I'm stuck on getting the nesting working properly. Please keep in mind, this is the first time I've ever used LINQ, so I'm a complete newbie at it. I have an xml file, which comes into the web app as a stream. The xml is pretty straightforward, basically following the following format:

```
 <root>
    <people>
        <person>
            <StuffToGet1>
            <StuffToGet2>
            ...
            <StuffToGetPARENT>
                <useless1>
                <useless2>
                ...
                <StuffToGetChild1>
                <StuffToGetChild2>
            </StuffToGetPARENT>
         </person>
    </people>
    </root>
```

Obviously, I have no problem with getting the Stuff To Get's that are on the top level. Currently, my Linq is pulling back EVERYTHING in . I want to filter that select on a subquery to ignore everything that isnt in StuffToGetChild tags. The tags will all be named the same thing,  (NOT Brand1, Brand2, etc). Below is what I have so far... please help!!

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(responseStream));
var People = from Person in xdoc.Descendants("Person")
                  where Person.Element("Role").Value != "Admin"
                  orderby Specialist.Element("Role").Value
                  select new
                  {
                  StuffToGet1 = Person.Element("StuffToGet1").Value,
                  StuffToGet2 = Person.Element("StuffToGet2").Value,
                  Brand = Person.Element("StuffToGetPARENT").Value
                          };


        gvTest.DataSource = People;
        gvTest.DataBind();
```

EDIT: I just realized something I said which might be a bit confusing. "Brand" is actually what's in the "StuffToGetChild" tags. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. In Brand property you want assign some collection of objects, which will be created from StuffToGetChild1, StuffToGetChild2 tags??

Comment: Correct. Most of the xml is very top down stuff, one level deep. Within the StuffToGetPARENT tag, there is a bunch of useless subtags, which I dont need. Then you get a few "Brand" subtags, which contains the info I need. I don't know the best way to return it, a list or collection, I'm not sure I'm new to working with LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can resolve this problem by another linq query inside first one.

```
from Person in xdoc.Descendants("Person")
              where Person.Element("Role").Value != "Admin"
              orderby Specialist.Element("Role").Value
              select new
              {
              StuffToGet1 = Person.Element("StuffToGet1").Value,
              StuffToGet2 = Person.Element("StuffToGet2").Value,
              Brand = (from x in 
                       Person.Descendants("StuffToGetChild1") select new 
                        {
                            ...
                        })
                      };
```